# The NativeScript Plugin Seed Demo Does Not Run

Tags: nativescript-plugin

We are trying to use our native codes in Nativescript therefore we tried to test nativeScript plugin seed. We follow the steps to in README however demo does not run and stops.

We tried all available version we could reach and applied the flow we see in guidance videos.

Last section of terminal messages:

> Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes. Webpack build
>   done! Copying template files... Unable to apply changes on device:
>   F2CB7B69-FE7F-4EE7-9150-133E604FBF18. Error is: zlib: unexpected end
>   of file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 134 npm ERR!
>   nativescript-tstpin@1.0.0 demo.ios: `npm run tsc && cd ../demo && tns
>   run ios --syncAllFiles --emulator` npm ERR! Exit status 134 npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the nativescript-tstpin@1.0.0 demo.ios script. npm
>   ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/hasanguner/.npm/_logs/2019-05-22T08_53_09_212Z-debug.log
>   Hasans-MacBook-Pro:src hasanguner$

After the messages in the terminal it stops. It would be great if anyone could help how to step over this starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I tried the following: On Mac:

sudo npm cache clean --force

Then worked fine.
If anyone tells me the reason it would be perfect.

Comment: if you have another question don't ask in a comment. Provide some explanation to your answer